# Kendo grid with DropDown, iterate grid setting drop down values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with ASP.NET MVC3, Jquery, & Kendo UI.

Here is a clip of how my grid is setup (I removed all irrelevant fields):

```
Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<MyProject.Models.Domain.Students>()
    .Name("Students")
    .Sortable(settings => settings.Enabled(false))
    .Filterable(settings => settings.Enabled(false))
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable(settings => settings.Enabled(true))     
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size: 85%;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.StudentId).Title("StudentId").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Title("Student Name").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.teacher).Title("Teacher")
                 .ClientTemplate("#=data.teacher ? teacher.teacherName : ''#").Width(150).Filterable(false);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                            .Batch(true)
                                            .ServerOperation(false)
                                            .Model(model =>
                                                {
                                                    model.Id(c => c.StudentId);
                                                    model.Field(c => c.teacher);                                                       
                                                })
                                                .Events(events => events.Error("Field_onError"))
                                                .Read(read => read.Action("_AjaxGetFields", "Student"))
                                                .Update("_AjaxUpdateFields", "Student")
                                                .Destroy("_AjaxDelFields", "Student"))
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("Fields_onDataBound")
                                .Change("onFieldSelect")
                                .Edit("onFieldEdit")
                                )
        .ToolBar(commands =>
            {
                commands.Save().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "saveField" }); 
            })
        .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height("375px"))
        .Selectable()
        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell)).Render();
```

Here is the template for the teacher drop down:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))
    .DataValueField("TeacherId")       
    .DataTextField("TeacherName")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("_SelectTeacherList", "Teacher").Data("onTeacherDataBinding");
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Events(e => e           
        .Change("dropdownlist_change")
        )
)
```

I have another drop down on the page that is not on the grid.  I have a jquery function that gets executed every time the drop down changes.  The drop down is a list of teachers.  When it changes I want to set the teacher column of every row of the grid to the same value and text pair that was selected in the drop down.

Here is what I have so far, you can see where the comment is that I need to put some code.  I am not sure how to do this:

```
function teachers_change()
{
    var teacherDL = $("#allTeach").data("kendoDropDownList");
    teachid = teacherDL.value();
    teachName = teacherDL.text();

    $("#Students tr").each(function ()
    {
        var tr = this;
        var cells = tr.cells;
        //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GET A REFERENCE TO THE DROP DOWN 
        //AND SET THE VALUE TO teachid AND THE TEXT TO teachName
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done automatically, if the name of the DropDownList that is generated is called as your property , then they should be bound via data-bind attribute.

In your case the DropDownList name should be "teacher". Rest should be done automatically and the whole dataItem that the Grid uses should be replaced with the DataItem of the DropDownList.

Comment: Peter, not sure I understand your answer.  Do you have the line of code that would set the dropdown list?  Remember teacherDL is not on the grid.  The reason I'm doing this is so there is an easy way for the user to assign 1 teacher to all of the students if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of hours on this, it may not be pretty, but it does the job.

If anyone has a better solution, please post!!!

```
grid.dataSource._data[this.rowIndex].teacher.teacherId = teachid ;
grid.dataSource._data[this.rowIndex].teacher.teacherName = teachName;
grid.dataSource._data[this.rowIndex].dirty = true;
TDIndex = (this.rowIndex * 17) +3;
grid.table[0].cells[TDIndex].innerHTML = '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' + teachName;
grid._data[this.rowIndex].teacher.teacherId = teachid;
grid._data[this.rowIndex].teacher.teacherName = teachName;
```

The first two lines and the last two lines directly modify the data source that the drop down is using.  The lines in the middle set the actual grid field so you see the selected value in the grid when the drop down is not open.